# Using Without Sharing apex class in a Managed Pacakge

Tags: managed-package, without-sharing

Can we use Without sharing class in a managed package?

We have a scenario where we want to query recent activities of Account, Contact and Opportunity and Custom_Object__c whenever we receive an inbound call from the third party API. As if the activities are private then we are not getting the intended records. Using without sharing on a class solves our issue. But we are not sure if this is going to work in a managed package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have quite a few "without sharing" classes in our managed package - we have many different "utility classes" (i.e. not directly user-facing code, such as Visualforce controllers or REST APIs, but rather for system processing, such as data maintenance batches, scheduled jobs, internal calculations etc.) that perform operations where sharing makes no sense at all. As sfdcfox said, this **is** a red flag for the security review and you need to explicitly document the reason for "without sharing" in each case.

We have done this by ensuring we have apexdoc comments on the classes along with explicit comments on the source code lines that are extracted by Checkmarx, like this:

```
global without sharing class SomeBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful { // Sharing False Positive: This is a utility class for data processing which must be ignorant of sharing rules and user permissions
```

That way, when the Salesforce Security Review Team view the Checkmarx report they can see the code is marked as a "false positive" and if they want the full detail they can read the apexdoc to see why.

Answer (score 2):

It will work in a managed package, but you may have problems passing the security review. This is a big red flag to the security team, and you should avoid using this keyword at all costs. However, there *are* some use cases where it might be appropriate, so you can try to make your case with the security review team. If your use case is not appropriate, they may offer another solution to the problem.